# How to open display block using div name?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one problem in display the block using div name .Here My code

```
<button   onClick="reply_click()">&#10799</button> 
<div id='id'  name='name' style="display: none;" >I am comming..</div>

<script>
        function reply_click() {
                //document.getElementById('id').style.display='block';
                document.getElementsByName('name').style.display='block';
        }
</script>
```

Using div id it will  display the block ,but using div name it's not working 
Any body give the sugesstion ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Out of curiosity why would you try targeting an element via the name attr when getElementById is so much faster ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `getElementsByName` returns an `nodelist` not a single element, so There should be

```
document.getElementsByName('name')[0].style.display='block';
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/89/)

Comment: I'm not sure that `getElementsByName()` will include `<div>` nodes in its result, because "name" is not a meaningful attribute for a `<div>`. *edit* nope I'm wrong :)

Comment: Yes I agree. I have this idea that there's *some* API that would ignore a "name" on a `<div>` but I don't know what; maybe the list of form elements on a `<form>` node?

Comment: @Pointy - According to [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259), only form elements would be included in an XHTML 1.0 document. In HTML documents, it says that elements that have a matching "name value" would be in the list. I'm not sure what that means, but I would have thought that would exclude div elements too. [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-getelementsbyname) is much clearer, it just matches on the name attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I think name is not an legal name to use it as value for name attribute. If this is the case, then use a proper legal name to use it as value of name attribute.

And, anyways try with different name as:

```
document.getElementsByName('divName')[0].style.display='block';
```